# How to start debugging slow Polymer perf?

Tags: polymer, polymer-1.0

I'm writing a Polymer based app and at some point the UI has gotten really slow to render and really slow to scroll.

Does anyone know of any resources or tips on the best way to get started debugging polymer performance issues?

Comment: you need to elaborate further. on (slow to render and really slow to scroll). where is the data coming from, what are you scrolling on eg (iron-list) ??? also put the structure code of your app in the question and any css. It could be a css issue like seting (position:fixed) for your list. That will really slow down scrolling

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Chrome Javascript Profiler is a pretty good place to start: https://developer.chrome.com/devtools/docs/cpu-profiling

Also, try [vulcanizing](https://github.com/Polymer/vulcanize) your components to speed up initial resource loading.